# Completely expand and simplify logical expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, logic

Consider a logical expression such as

```
expr = (a == b + q - w || c == d) && (q + c - d == w || e == r);
```

I wonder if there is a function that would completely expand the nested brackets and fully simplify each case, e.g.:

```
expr // ExpandAndSimplify
```

> (a + w == b + q && c + r == d + e) || (a == b && q == w) ||
>
> (c == d && q == w) || (c == d && r == e)

Is there such a function in Mathematica? Or maybe one can implement it somehow?

Comment: Does `expr // Reduce`  give you what you want?

Comment: @AndrewNorton Oh, yes it does, thanks for pointing it out!